# Can't generate App specific shared secret code

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store, shared-secret

I have to implement auto-renewable `in-app purchase` in ios app and I have "`app manager`" permission to access my client's `app store connect` account. When I click on "`app specific shared secret`" then it doesn't show me an option for generating it (please use image link from my comment). Stackoverflow is asking for 10 reputations for uploading image so I added image link in comment.

I also tried master shared secret which shows me an option to generate it but when I hit generate then it goes back to appstoreconnect home screen. When I open "`master shared secret`" again for viewing code then it still doesn't show any code.

I have tried following

1. My client's paid and free app contracts are in effect and their status is active,
2. My client has filled tax info, bank info and contact info.
3. I created 4 in-app purchases with complete metadata and review info. They were ready to submit
4. I also submitted a binary with in-app purchase and rejected it. so in-app purchase's current status is "`waiting for review`".
5. I have waited for 2-3 days after contracts are in effect and tax info is submitted with bank info.
   6 Tried several times to generate shared secret.

But it is still not working. I don't know what is wrong.

Do I need "admin" permission instead of "app manager" for generating shared secret?

Do I need to wait till in-app purchase's current status becomes "Approved"? Can't I generate shared secret if status is not "Approved"?

These are the only two things I could thought as a possible reason of this issue. If there is another possible reason then please let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/yJHc1NYT

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how to fix it? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem to generate the `shared-secret` as a `app manager`. No error is displayed when I try to do it.

I ask to my admin to try and on the first modal screen, a button "Generate a shared-secret" was present. So yes, you need to have admin permission to see the button.

Comment: Yeh, 'app manager' can only read the 'shared-secret' if already generated by any of the 'admin' of your 'Apple Developer Account'. If you don't see it, you need to ask the 'Admin' to generate it first.

Answer (score 4):

It has moved to General > App Information

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

[image]

More details at [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662885)